# Make checkbox value checked with jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am experiencing trouble as I want to make checkbox value checked when site loads and the visitor can uncheck it. id field is dynamic inside input so I need to check based on name and value I suppose.

I used jQuery to make it checked, but nothing happens

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
  $("input.myclass[name='test-case'][value='yes']").prop("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="test-case[]" id="cbopt-AAljenwo" value="yes">
```

Not sure if this is correct value of marking input as checked. User also can uncheck box if he doesn't like the option. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: 1) Look at the name in the HTML and the name you've set in the selector. 2) there's no class on that checkbox element 3) If you want this to work on load, just use `checked="checked"` in HTML

Comment: Use good old html and add `checked` attribute to the checkbox

Comment: you've got an id. why not use that?

Comment: @Yishmeray `id field is dynamic inside input so I need to check based on name and value`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan not able to insert code in HTML as this is generated through builder. But can add jquery code which will mark it as checked. Not sure how to do it

Comment: @ron9 thanks for clarifying, I added an answer for you

Comment: If the builder is under your control can't you tell it to add the `checked` attribute to the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to achieve this would be to put a `checked` attribute in the HTML. However you state that the HTML is being generated for you, so you don't have that option.

The second best option would be to target the checkbox by its `id`, however that has the same issue for you as the `id` is dynamically generated at runtime.

Your last resort is to then select the element by its `name` and `value`, which is what your jQuery is trying to do, however there's a couple of issues. Firstly the checkbox you're targeting has no class and the name attribute has a `[]` suffix which you need to include. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('input[name="test-case[]"][value="yes"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="test-case[]" value="yes">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add checked attribute to the input element to make it checked when the page is loaded:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" checked />` would be enough. There is no reason to assign a value to the attribute. *"[checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox#checked) - Boolean; if present, the checkbox is toggled on by default"* - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox#Additional_attributes)

Answer (score 0):

simply that:

```js
const theChexbox = document.querySelector("input[name='test-case[]']")

theChexbox.checked = true
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="test-case[]" id="cbopt-AAljenwo" value="yes">
```